# Android 12 Splash Icon Issue

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen

I am doing a flutter development but on android for the splash page.

I am having issues with my splash icon, its not turning out as I expected. I do have a colored background, but my splash icon is displaying zoomed in, distorted and kind-of pixelated.

Things I have done are, double checked dimensions, created the icon with different dimensions and densities, followed the instructions and requirements on android development docs, I even followed the example in the documentation lol.

Here are the codes:

```
values-night/styles.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is on -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             the Flutter engine draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">#FFCF4A</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/trans_icon_2</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.

         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

```
values-night-v31/styles.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">#FFCF4A</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/trans_icon_2</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.
         
         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

```
values-v31/styles.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">#FFCF4A</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/trans_icon_2</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.
         
         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

```
AndroidManifest.xml

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="">
    <application
        android:label=""
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name=""
            android:value="high_importance_channel"/>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
</manifest>
```

Here is the output of my
 [splash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoPsw.png)

Comment: can you share how splash page looks like ?

Comment: you need to follow the android splash screen API guide for icons. https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#dimensions

Comment: @ChiragThummar I already did, just as I mentioned, I even mimicked the dimension and density of the example.

Comment: @HardikMehta here https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoPsw.png, sorry!

Comment: If you have really follow the guideline then this must not be issue. Here I can see that you have used Icon size of 512 * 512 which is actually a problem here. and your must use 192 *192 icon size so that it will not be cropped

Comment: is 192x192 xxxhdpi or what?